# Difference between "ClassA object = new ClassA();" and "new ClassA();"?

Tags: java

I don't know if this has already been asked since I can't find it anywhere.

So, recently I came across this feature in IntelliJ IDEA where it says transform expressions.

Here is the picture:

[image]

What I want to know is that what is the difference between `ClassA object = new ClassA();` and `new ClassA();`.

Is there any functional differences or anything else that may impact normal code functioning in any way?

Comment: No, there's no real difference. The only thing is that the unused variable `testClass` clutters the code.

Comment: FWIW, i'd consider a class which does all its work inside the default constructor a possible design smell

Comment: @GyroGearless it doesn't do much it only initializes values I just did not pass arguments in the constructor here

Comment: @Ak222 but the values it initializes must be non-instance variables, otherwise they are simply lost after the statement; and having to create an instance of a class to update non-instance (e.g. static) variables is... odd.

Comment: @AndyTurner This is the code `observableList.add(new Rankings(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3),
                        resultSet.getString(4))); ` what I was using before was initializing an object then using it even though I never needed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code contains a variable

```
ClassA object = new ClassA();
```

which you never use later in the code, you can eliminate the variable and the `new ClassA()` expression.

However, if creating an instance of `ClassA()` has some side effects relevant to your program (i.e., you need the constructor of `ClassA` to be executed even if you don't do anything with the created `ClassA` instance later), you can replace that statement with a statement that creates an instance without assigning it to a variable:

```
new ClassA();
```

Such a statement makes it clear that the created instance is not expected to be accessed later by following code.

However, both statements will function the same (though the first statement may result in a warning saying you declared a variable that you are not using).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `new ClassA()` and don't do anything with it, that instance is unreachable unless you're storing it somehow, somewhere (for example, in a `List`). If it has any side effects, however (like printing), those side effects will still occur. If you use `ClassA object = new ClassA();`, you'll be able to use that specific instance later in the code due to the name binding.

You'd normally use `new ClassA()` when you want it to be anonymous because you don't need a long-standing reference. For example:

```
List<ClassA> instances = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    instances.add(new ClassA());
}
```

or

```
void doSomethingWithClass(ClassA c) {
    // do something
}

doSomethingWithClass(new ClassA());
```

Answer (score 0):

By this statement, `ClassA object = new ClassA();` , you are creating a reference. Whereas when you write `new ClassA();` It is an **anonymous** object that you are creating. It is to be noted that If you have to use an object only once, an anonymous object is a good approach.

[See more info about anonymous objects here](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-and-class-in-java#:%7E:text=Anonymous%20simply%20means%20nameless.,object%20is%20a%20good%20approach.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Two instances have been created for ClassA. one instance is called "object" and the other instance is "anonymous".